# Why can't I specify TestAdaptersPaths in my runsettings file?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, azure, vstest, runsettings

I'm working on getting NUnit tests running pre-deploy to Azure so I built an application to run tests:

https://github.com/EdLichtman/HelloAzureCI

When I run this on my own PC everything works correctly, 3 unit tests pass and one fails (as I expect should happen, I'm testing Environment AppSettings)

However when I deploy to Azure I get the error: Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration'. Unexpected XmlElement: 'TestAdapterPaths'.

I even automated the creation of the .runsettings file in Powershell to ensure that the Direct path (D:\home\etc...) was initialized as the TestAdaptersPaths so that I could test to see if it just couldn't find the testAdaptersPaths path that I was specifying but it's still getting the error.

I'm using the exact spelling and tree structure from Microsoft's guide to .runsettings, why is it not working?

Comment: I really want to know why it's working so I'm not answering my own question, but if anyone comes here with the same problem the solution I used is: Because I don't need anything more than TestAdapterPath I added /TestAdapterPath:[Source] instead of an entire settings file

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you were missing "**s**". try using `TestAdaptersPaths` rather than `TestAdapterPaths`.